# Kivy - Mudar posição do cursor do teclado (caret) após formatar textinput com máscara

Tags: python, python-kivy, kivy

Em um TextInput no qual o usuário digita o CPF, controlo a validação e formatação em um evento on_Text.
Após ter digitado os 11 dígitos e validado o CPF, eu formato com a máscara, porém, após formatar, o
cursor fica parado na posição do 11º caractere.
Tento mover o cursor usando a propriedade "cursor" que o TextInput disponibiliza, mas não surte efeito.

Código de criação do componente em KVLang:

```
 TextInputCpf:
        id: txt_cpf
        multiline: False
        size_hint_x: .16
        pos_hint: { 'x':.02 , 'center_y':.66 }
```

Código Python:

```
class TextInputCpf(TextInput):

    def on_text(self, instance, value):
        if len(value) == 11:
            if uteis.validar_cpf(value):
                self.text = uteis.formatar_cpf(value)
                self.cursor = (len(self.text), 0)

# função simples de formatação
# está no arquivo uteis.py
def formatar_cpf(cpf: str) -> str:
  return '{}.{}.{}-{}'.format(cpf[:3], cpf[3:6], cpf[6:9], cpf[9:11])
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        if not substring.isnumeric():
            substring = ""

        texto_completo = self.text + substring
        
        if len(texto_completo) == 11:
            if uteis.validar_cpf(texto_completo):
                self.text = uteis.formatar_cpf(texto_completo)
                #self.cursor = (len(self.text), 0)
                self.do_cursor_movement("cursor_end")
                substring = ""
        elif len(texto_completo) > 14:
            self.text = texto_completo[0:14]
            substring = ""

        return super().insert_text(substring, from_undo=from_undo)
```